# Azure pipeline expand each parameter when using template

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have the following setup, a template file, and a pipeline that extends the template. I am wondering is it possible to dynamically add all parameters to extends' parameter?

Template.yml

```
parameters:
- name: Location
  type: string
  default: 'eastus'
```

Washington.yml

```
parameters:
- name: Location
  type: string
  default: 'westus'

extends:
  template: Template.yml
  parameters:
    Location: ${{ parameters.Location }}
```

I can do something like this but I think it doesn't work because the shadowed `parameters` variable will be used instead of root level `parameters`.

```
parameters:
- name: Location
  type: string
  default: 'westus'

extends:
  template: Template.yml
  parameters:
  - ${{ each param in parameters }}
    ${{ param.Name  }}: ${{ param.Value }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```yaml
parameters:
- name: Location
  type: string
  default: 'westus'

extends:
  template: Template.yml
  parameters:
    ${{ each param in parameters }}:
      ${{ param.Key }}: ${{ param.Value }}
```

So you had small syntax issues.

It printed:

[image]

Assuming that template is:

```yaml
parameters:
- name: Location
  type: string
  default: 'eastus'

steps:
- script: echo ${{ parameters.Location }}
```